# When does RTCIceConnectionState.closed get fired

Tags: webrtc

From Mozilla [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/iceConnectionState) it says

> "closed": The ICE agent for this RTCPeerConnection has shut down and is
> no longer handling requests.

When or how does a RTCPeerConnection gets **shut down**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This state will in general not fire. The only way to reach it is to call the `close()` method on the RTCPeerConnection and calling close will not fire events. Try this:

```
const pc = new RTCPeerConnection();
pc.close();
pc.iceConnectionState;
```